# input numerico en php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo que pide un numero

```
    <html>
<h1>Estadios </h1>
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("error al conectar");
mysqli_select_db ($conexion,"parcial")or die ("error al conectar");
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"select * from estadio");
$nfilas = mysqli_num_rows ($consulta);  
if ($nfilas > 0)
{print "<br>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$nfilas; $i++) {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array ($consulta);
        print " Codigo: " . $fila["codigo"] ;   print "<br>";
        print " Nombre: " . $fila["nombre"] ;   print "<br>";
        print " Año apertura: " . $fila["fechaApertura"] ;  print "<br>";
        print " Capacidad: " . $fila["capacidad"] ." personas" ; print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";
    }
}
?> 
<form method="POST" action="prueba.php">
<h2>Digite el codigo del estadio para buscar los encuentros proximos</h2>
Codigo:<input type ="input" name="codigo" placeholder="Digite el codigo" required>
 <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
</form>

</html>
```

El siguiente archivo php que se encarga de recibir lo que el usuario ingreso y buscar el codigo en la base de datos

```
<html>
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("error al conectar");
mysqli_select_db ($conexion,"parcial")or die ("error al conectar");

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

$consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"SELECT `codigo` FROM `estadio` WHERE codigo = $codigo");

$Codigo=0;
if ($consulta) {
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
    $Codigo=$row['codigo'];    
}
if ($Codigo == $codigo){
    if ($codigo == 10){
    header("location: jugadores.php");
    }else if ($codigo == 11){
    header("location: jugadoresv.php");
    }
}else
{
echo "Lo sentimos, este codigo de estadio no se encuentra en nuestra base de datos";
}
?>
</html>
```

La peticion es si me pueden ayudar a que digamos, si el usuario ingresa un numero X pues este vaya y lo busque en la base de datos,
hasta el momento solo pude hacer que reconozca numeros pero si los valido, quiero hacerlo para cualquier numero sin hacer esa validacion de "$codigo == 11"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregarle a los nombres de tus archivos `php` el código y en tu condición solo verificar si la consulta te genero un resultado, ya que solo necesitas saber si lo encontró en la base.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if ($consulta) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)){//si regreso un resultado 
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
        $Codigo=$row['codigo'];        
        header("location: jugadores".$Codigo.".php");//header("location: jugadores.php?codigo=".$Codigo);
    }else{
       echo "Lo sentimos, este codigo de estadio no se encuentra en nuestra base de datos";
    }
}else{
   echo "error en la consulta";
}
```

otras de las opciones es pasarla el código como parámetro a `jugadores.php` y en este recibir el código con un `$_GET["codigo"]` para su uso.

```
header("location: jugadores.php?codigo=".$Codigo);
```